# Educational videos for Books of Nevi'im and Ketuvim?

Tags: product-recommendation, chinuch-education, navi-prophets

I seem to recall viewing animated and narrated videos of stories from the Early Prophets, Nevi'im, a few decades ago.

Can anyone recommend any educational and reliably truthful animated and/or well-produced video series of stories in Nach, which are fitting for children and young adults?

In the quest for successful education techniques in the realm of Jewish education, I believe that finding such a video series would be directly relevant to Judaism and our collective continued understanding.

Comment: here is a book called "Journey Through Nach"
includes: Chapter summaries on every chapter in Nach; Divrei Torah on Nach; Charts, Maps, Timelines, and a reference to every Haftarah; and A selection of essays about Nach
https://seforimdeals.com/store15/index.php/all-books-seforim/nach/journey-through-nach-2-vol-set.html